Sum of two dice
I have a question about the solution  of the following problem. More details at the end of the post.
Problem:
Imagine rolling two dice. Consider the sum of the outcome. What is the probability that the sum of the two dice equals $k$? Which sum has the highest probability?
Solution:
Let $\Omega=\{(i,j): 1 \leq i,j \leq 6\}$.
Let $A_k$ be the outcome that the sum of both dice is equal to $k$ (where $2 \leq k \leq 12$).
If $\omega$ is the outcome where the sum is equal to $k$ , then $\omega$ is of the form $\omega=(i,k-i)$ with $1 \leq i \leq 6$ and $1 \leq k-i \leq 6$.
$(*)$
Thus
$(k-i) \lor 1 \leq i \leq 6 \land (k-i)$.
We will write $a \land b=\min(a,b)$ and $a \lor b =\max(a,b)$. This means:
for $k \leq 7, 1 \leq i \leq k-1$ we get $|A_k|=k-i$
for $7 \leq k \leq 12$, $k-6 \leq i \leq 6$ we get $|A_k|=13-k$.
And $\mathcal{P}(A_k)$ is maximal for $k=7$, yielding $\mathcal{P}(A_k)= 1/6$.
My Questions:
I do get everything said until the $(*)$ sign.

I do not see how one would get from  If $\omega$ is a outcome (i.e.
$\omega \in A_k$), then $\omega$ is of the form $\omega=(i,k-i)$ with
$1 \leq i \leq 6$ and $1 \leq k-i \leq 6$.

To

Thus  $(k-i) \lor 1 \leq i \leq 6 \land (k-i)$.

I also am somewhat confused where the $\lor$ and $\land$ signs came from.
So I couldn't really follow anything after $(*)$.
I would have probably just written $A_k$ explicitly. I.e.
$A_2=\{(1,1)\}$
$A_3=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$
$A_4=\{(1,3),(3,1),(2,2)\}$
.
.
.
and so on.
Although my approach would be fine too (I guess), it seems very tedious to do. Especially if one increases the amount of dice. (For example if I would consider the sum of $10$ dice).
My request would be if someone could please explain the solution of this example in detail. (I am also interested in other approaches, but my knowledge on probability theory isn't that big. I recently started learning about random variables.)

Do you mean $k-i$ instead of $k-1$ throughout?

Clearly it should have been $k-i$.  After all, $i+k-1$ is only equal to $k$ if $i=1$.

The solution seems to be missing some words: "$\omega$ is a outcome" is not the same as $\omega \in A_k$. Instead of "$\omega$ is a outcome," it should say something like "$\omega$ is a outcome in which the sum is $k$." It's unclear whether you're having difficulty with the actual ideas of the solution or just difficulty with the incomplete and inaccurate language of the solution. If we suppose that the sum of the dice is $k$ and we also suppose that the first die rolled the number $i$, what is the number on the second die?

The pdf of the sum of 2 uniformly distributed random variables (either in the discrete or the continuous case) has a triangular shape with mode = mean = midpoint between the two extreme cases.

@DavidK No, I do not get the idea of the solution. Regarding the inaccurate language, I think that I just translated it wrong into englisch.

My Problem is that I don't see how one gets from $\omega=(i,k-i)$ to $(k−i)∨1≤i≤6∧(k−i)$.

English is strange.  Singular die, plurao dice.  So this is the sum of two dice (not dices).

Indeed the solution as originally shown was not really properly written,
and the edits to the problem have not completely fixed it.
For example, as copied here, the symbols $\lor$ and $\land$ are used in an unusual way; the author of the solution realized that these unusual meanings of the symbols needed to be defined, but they waited too long to define them. I assume the text shown here is faithful to the original, because why else would you write it this way? But the way it is written, when we get to the end of the sentence containing the formula
$(k-1) \lor 1 \leq i \leq 6 \land (k-1),$
the implication is that we should have seen enough by that point to understand what the formula means. And we have not seen enough, because the definitions of the symbols are postponed until the following paragraph.
In fact, these unusual definitions are completely unnecessary in this proof.
The author likes to write $a \land b$ when they mean $\min(a,b)$ -- yes, that is something that can be explained, but why not just write $\min(a,b)$ and save the effort of having to explain and understand this notation?
So here's my version of the same solution, lightly edited.
I have used $\min(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $\max(\cdot,\cdot)$ instead of $\land$ and $\lor,$
making it unnecessary to redefine $\land$ and $\lor$ as $\min(\cdot,\cdot)$ and
$\max(\cdot,\cdot).$ I have made some other changes such as writing "event" rather than "outcome" to describe a set that may contain multiple outcomes.
There were also some places where the number $1$ appeared in the original version of the question where a different value evidently should have been written. I have tried to replace the $1$ with the appropriate value in those cases.

Corrected solution
Let $\Omega=\{(i,j): 1 \leq i,j \leq 6\}$.
Let $A_k$ be the event that the sum of both dice is equal to $k$ (where $2 \leq k \leq 12$).
If $\omega$ is a outcome in which the sum is $k$ (i.e. $\omega \in A_k$), then $\omega$ is of the form $\omega=(i,k-i)$ with $1 \leq i \leq 6$ and $1 \leq k-1 \leq 6$.
Thus
$$\max((k-6), 1) \leq i \leq \min(6, (k-1)).$$
This means:
for $k \leq 7,$ $1 \leq i \leq k-1$ and we get $|A_k|=k-1.$
for $7 \leq k \leq 12$, $k-6 \leq i \leq 6$ and we get $|A_k|=13-k.$
And $\mathcal{P}(A_k)$ is maximal for $k=7$, yielding $\mathcal{P}(A_k)= 1/6$.

Now to explain some of the details:
We say $\max((k-6), 1) \leq i$ because we need to have $i + j = k,$
which means $i = k - j,$ but $k - j$ can never be smaller than $k - 6$
since $j$ can never be larger than $6.$
Therefore $i \geq k - 6.$ But we also know $i \geq 1.$
To say that $i$ is greater than or equal to each of two numbers is to say that $i$ is greater than or equal to the greatest of those two numbers.
That is, $i \geq \max((k-6), 1).$
Similarly, since $j \geq 1,$ $k - j$ cannot be greater than $k - 1,$
and therefore $i \leq k - 1.$ But also $i \leq 6.$
Therefore $i \leq \min((k - 1), 6).$
For $k \leq 7$ we see that $k - 6$ is never greater than $1,$ so
$\max((k-6), 1) = 1.$
Also, when $k \leq 7,$ $k - 1$ is never greater than $6,$ so
$\min((k - 1), 6) = k - 1.$
So when $k \leq 7,$ the formula $\max((k-6), 1) \leq i \leq \min(6, (k-1))$
becomes $1 \leq i \leq k-1.$
Similarly when $k \geq 7,$ then $\max((k-6), 1)$ simplifies to $k - 6$
and $\min((k - 1), 6)$ simplifies to $6.$
Now that we know what the minimum and maximum values of $i$ are, we can count how many values $i$ can have, and that is the size of $A_k.$

Solution as originally posted
For reference, the following is a copy of the solution as originally posted, before people tried to "fix" it by editing the question or telling you to edit the question.
Parts of the solution do need to be edited; I have marked these by drawing rectangular boxes around them. But the things that really cause trouble are that $k - 1$ appears in two places where it should be $k - i$ and one place where it should be $k - 6$ and that the definitions of $\lor$ and $\land$ are given too late.
Let $\Omega=\{(i,j): 1 \leq i,j \leq 6\}$.
Let $A_k$ be the $\boxed{\text{outcome}}$ that the sum of both dice is equal to $k$ (where $2 \leq k \leq 12$).
If $\omega$ is $\boxed{\text{a outcome}}$ (i.e. $\omega \in A_k$), then $\omega$ is of the form $\omega=(i,k-\boxed{1})$ with $1 \leq i \leq 6$ and $1 \leq k-\boxed{1} \leq 6$.
Thus
$(k-\boxed{1}) \lor 1 \leq i \leq 6 \land (k-1)$.
$\boxed{\text{We will write }a \land b=\min(a,b)\text{ and }a \lor b =\max(a,b).}$ This means:
for $k \leq 7, 1 \leq i \leq k-1$ we get $|A_k|=k-1$
for $7 \leq k \leq 12$, $k-6 \leq i \leq 6$ we get $|A_k|=13-k$.
And $\mathcal{P}(A_k)$ is maximal for $k=7$, yielding $\mathcal{P}(A_k)= 1/6$.

Very detailed. Thank you very much!

@NTc5 Glad to help.

not an aswer - a long comment which could be helpfil.
Note that $k-i\leq6$, hence $6\land (k-i) = k-i$. And as $k-i\geq1$, you have $(k-i)\lor1=k-i$. So the inequality you are a bit confused about is $$k-i\leq i\leq k-i$$
This is just to rewrite and make things a bit clear, as you were unhappy with the max and min symboles.
